# Why is there an "attribute error" inside the condition of the while loop? but not the if statement within the while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I am writing an algorithm to merge two sorted list from leetcode. I noticed that the conditionals in the while loops and outermost if statements were throwing

Attribute Error: 'Nontype' object has no attribute 'val'

*I know this code isn't correctly implemented merge two sorted list*

After I deleted all the '.val' methods inside the while conditionals and outermost if statements, it compiled normally. Then why is it that the conditionals in the if statements within the while loops have no problem of "attribute error"?

*I am aware that this code isn't correctly implemented merge two sorted list*

```
class ListNode:
     def __init__(self, x):
         self.val = x
         self.next = None

class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        result = []
        while l1.val != None and l2.val != None:
            if l1.val >= l2.val:
                result.append(l2.val)
                l2 = l2.next
            else:
                result.append(l1.val)
                l1 = l1.next
        if l1.val != None:
            while l1.val != None:
                result.append(l1.val)
                l1 = l1.next
        else:
            while l2.val != None:
                result.append(l2.val)
                l2 = l2.next
        return result
```

Comment: Well you check for `l1.val != None` but that doesn't mean `l1.next is not None`. So in the next iteration `l1 = l1.next` and it might be that `l1 is None`.

Comment: Oh shoot... that's right.. thank you